# SwiftUI Tutorial PresentationButton Bug

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I started to experiment with the new SwiftUI framework, announced on the WWDC 2019 and started the tutorial on https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui.

Now I came to the point where to connect the Profile to the HomeScreen via the `PresentationButton`. More precisely I am talking about this section of code in `Home.swift`:

```
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                PresentationButton(
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
                        .padding(),
                    destination: ProfileHost()
                )
            )
```

When I first click on the button the Profile Sheet appears just fine, but when I dismiss it and then click on the button again nothing happens.

Does anyone know why this is the case ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a bug in SwiftUI.
It is probably linked to the fact that `onDisappear` is never called.
You can verify that by adding

```swift
.onAppear{
  print("Profile appeared")
}.onDisappear{
  print("Profile disappeared")
}
```

to `ProfileHost` view. It would make sense that an `appear` should be balanced by a `disappear` for the dismissal to be complete.

It is possible to work around it by implementing a function that returns a `PresentationButton` that "depends" on a state variable.

```swift
@State var profilePresented: Int = 0
func profileButton(_ profilePresented: Int) -> some View {
  return PresentationButton(
    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
      .imageScale(.large)
      .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
      .padding(),
    destination: ProfileHost(),
    onTrigger: {
      let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime, execute: {
        self.profilePresented += 1
      })
  })
}
```

And replace

```swift
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
      PresentationButton(
          Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
              .imageScale(.large)
              .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
              .padding(),
          destination: ProfileHost()
      )
  )
```

with

```swift
.navigationBarItems(trailing: self.profileButton(self.profilePresented))
```

I highly recommend to not use this "solution" and just report the bug to Apple.

Comment: You are right, the on onDisappear method is never called. I assume this will be the root cause of the error. Already reported the bug, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that it is a bug of SwiftUI and we should contact Apple for this stuff. Hopefully it can be fixed in next beta

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to solve this issue is by leaving the destination: parameter on its own and have the Image object in the curly braces:

```
PresentationButton(destination: ProfileHost()) {
    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
        .imageScale(.large)
        .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
        .padding()
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm using and the button still only fires once. I think it's a wait for beta3 situation. `PresentationButton(destination: MessageListView().environmentObject(userData)) {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
            }`

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Beta 3.  I also had the same issue, where PresentationButton (now PresentationLink) was only firing once when embedded in .navigationBarItems.

Comment: I'm using Beta 3 and this still isn't working for me. Care to share your working solution?

Answer (score -2):

This was a bug resolved in Xcode 11 Beta2: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_2_release_notes.

With the updated API the following should work:

```
PresentationButton(destination:ProfileHost()) {
    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
    .imageScale(.large)
    .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
    .padding()
}
```

Comment: Using Xcode 11 Beta2 and I'm still getting the same behaviour: ie the button will show the profile sheet the first time, but it won't fire again. I checked the release notes and couldn't find anything relevant to `PresentationButton` (it wasn't mentioned actually). Seems like a wait for beta 3 to me...

Comment: This portion of code gives me different kind of error, It shows "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call, Insert '<#Label#>, ' ". And if I give it a label, it works but it shows the label text instead of person widgets. Anyone has any solution?