# SwiftUI PresentationButton fails to build - Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a `PresentationButton` in SwiftUI. I keep getting the following error:

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
>   Insert '<#Label#>, '

I am using Xcode Version 11.0 beta.

This is my SwiftUI file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeList : View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsHorizontalIndicator: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 5/) { item in
                    PresentationButton(destination: ContentView()) {
                        CourseView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct HomeList_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeList()
    }
}
#endif

struct CourseView : View {
    var body: some View {
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Build an app with Swift UI")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .color(Color.white)
                .padding(20)
                .lineLimit(4)
                .frame(width: 120)

            Spacer()

            Image("Illustration1")
            }
            .background(Color("background3"))
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .frame(width: 246, height: 360)
            .shadow(color: Color("backgroundShadow3"), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're on beta 1? You should probably upgrade to the latest (beta 5), if you would like to get help here. A **lot** has changed. For once, PresentationButton has been deprecated and no longer available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @kontiki stated, PresentationButton has been deprecated and no longer available.

A replacement that you could use is `NavigationLink`. This should work like `PresentationButton`. You will also need to change `showsHorizontalIndicator: false` to `.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)`

Also take out the `/` in your `ForEach(0 ..< 5/)`. This could be another reason for your errors.

```
struct HomeList : View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 5) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                        CourseView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you make these changes you should proceed error free. Good luck with the course: https://designcode.io/swiftui-course, I've enjoyed it. I'm not trying to plug it, just could see that he was following that tutorial.

Comment: this doesn't work in beta6. After i used NavigationView combine with NavigationLink, it does worked.

Answer (score -1):

After i used NavigationView combine with NavigationLink, it does worked

[swiftUI PresentaionLink does not work second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063633/swiftui-presentaionlink-does-not-work-second-time/57087399#57087399)

this worked for me